# Cannot move exactly to bottom of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css

I cannot move exactly to bottom of scrollbar. I am reaching a bit
upper to the bottom.
[image]

My code is-

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        var log = document.getElementById('log')
        log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight
        

        if (event.data !== '') {
          console.log(event.data)
          var newP = document.createElement('p')
          newP.innerHTML += event.data
          log.appendChild(newP)
        }
        
      }
```

I have tried adding and subtracting some values to log.scrollTop but no change was observed.

Comment: Why are you scrolling down before you create the element? Seems to me that the scrolling height is shorter because you check it before it is extended with more pixels from the new p element

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't initialize the height to the scrollbar.
Since that you want to increase the height of the scrollbar when a new

html element is added you should just update the height of the scrollbar when you add a new p in other words, you should update it when you click on send.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however your answer is unclear, it would be good if you at least provided an updated code sample.

Comment: i didn't want to request clarification or expose a critique, i just wrote badly my answer.